# Post form i themeplate Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a form to integrate in WordPress. How can i prevent the form from displaying start.php as an new single page when submitting?. I would like to stay in the startform div inside the template. Right now I'm shipped to a new start.php page?

I've tried to change the action to correct path to start.php but it's still same problem?

My file is start.php, I'm using this code to display it:

```
<div class="startform">
<?php get_template_part( 'start' )?>
<div>
```

The form is in start.php:

```
<form method="post" action="start.php">
<input type="submit" id="up_vote" name="vote" value="newmember" /> 
<input type="submit" id="down_vote" name="vote" value="oldmember" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using AJAX?

Comment: @henrywright I thought that if i used the get_template_part i would not need it? But maybe I'm misstaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution by adding the insert script on same page instead of action="start"

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" id="up_vote" name="vote" value="newmember" /> 
<input type="submit" id="down_vote" name="vote" value="oldmember" />
</form>
```